# Why can I not clear the interval?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why `clearInterval` is not working for me. In the interval I display a 2D array in a table format and then update the array, and repeat over and over.

Why is `clearInterval` not working?

JavaScript in head:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var tabl = document.getElementById('ordersTable');
    var l = tabl.rows.length;
    var w = tabl.rows[0].cells.length;
    alert("Width:" + w);
    var array1 = new Array(l);
    var array2 = new Array(l);
    initialize();
    alert(JSON.stringify(array1));
    var st = setInterval(function () {
        display(array1);
        newArray();
        //alert(JSON.stringify(array1));
    }, 3000);

    function stopTime() {
        clearInterval(st);
    }

    function display(array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                var tr = tabl.rows[i];
                var cll = tr.cells[j];
                var ct = cll.innerHTML = array[i][j];
                if (array[i][j] == 1) {
                    $(cll).css("color", "red");
                } else {
                    $(cll).css("color", "black");
                }
                cll.id = array1[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    function initialize() {
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            array1[i] = new Array(w);
            array2[i] = new Array(w);
            for (var j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
                array1[i][j] = rand;
            }
        }
    }

    function newArray() {
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
                array1[i][j] = rand;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML in body:

```
<table id="ordersTable">
    <tr><td>Row 1</td><td> Row 1.2</td><td>Row 1.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td><td> Row 2.2</td><td>Row 2.3 </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td><td> Row 3.2 </td><td>Row 3.3</td></tr>
</table>

<button onclick="stopTime()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: move Var st = '' above the $(window).load(function(){

Comment: @SLaks I upvoted your comment but that was just poor indentation - this is not a variable problem

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for fixing that indetation!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `stopTime()` is not a global function, so it can't be found by your `onclick="stopTime()"`.

To fix it, move both the `stopTime()` function and the `st` variable to the global scope.

```
var st;

function stopTime() {
    clearInterval(st);
}

$(window).load(function () {
    //...
    st = setInterval(function () {
        display(array1);
        newArray();
        //alert(JSON.stringify(array1));
    }, 3000);

    // ...
});
```

---

Or bind the `onclick` handler inside the `onload` function.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    //...
    var st = setInterval(function () {
        display(array1);
        newArray();
        //alert(JSON.stringify(array1));
    }, 3000);

    document.getElementById("my_button").onclick = function() {
        clearInterval(st);
    };

    //...
});
```

```
<table id="ordersTable">
    <tr><td>Row 1</td><td> Row 1.2</td><td>Row 1.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td><td> Row 2.2</td><td>Row 2.3 </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td><td> Row 3.2 </td><td>Row 3.3</td></tr>
</table>

<button id="my_button">Stop</button>
```

Comment: <s>How would he fix it?</s> Wow, that was fast.

Comment: Actually, keeping the varialbe local but set the click-handler inside the load-closure is the nicer way of fixing it... using global variables / adding properties to `window` is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid global variables and fix the issue by dynamically attaching the listener and keeping references to required variables in closures, e.g.:

Add an id to the button (or other method for identifying it):

```
<button type="button" id="stopButton">Stop</button>
```

Add the listener from the load function, something like:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    function stopTime() {
        if (st) {
            clearInterval(st);
        }
    }
    var st = ...;

    ...

    $('#stopButton').click(function(){stopTime()})
});
```